# Javascript - Show a div section set as hidden

Tags: javascript, html

I know there are A LOT of Qs on hiding-showing a div: I tried them all but somehow nothing seems to work.

I have a form and on loading the page div 1 shows. Once user hits the "Next" button then div 2 (previously not displayed) needs to show. What I would need help with is get the div 2 displayed upon click of the Next button

here is one of my many attempts:

```
        <div>
        table 1
        </div>

<button name="next" onclick="javascript:showDiv();"> Next </button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function showDiv() {
           div = document.getElemntById('dynamic');
           div.style.visibility = "visible";       
    }
</script>

<div id="dynamic" style="display:none"> 
table 2   
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  
</div>        
    </form>  

</body>
```

If anyone at all could help me I would be most grateful!! Thank you

Comment: Typo: `div = document.getElemntById('dynamic');` should be `div = document.getElementById('dynamic');`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to switch between `"display:none"` and `"display:block"` to hide and show the div.
Also you function should be `document.getElementById` instead of `document.getElemntById`

```js
 function showDiv() {
           div = document.getElementById('dynamic');
           div.style.display = "block";       
    }
```

```html
<button name="next" onclick="javascript:showDiv();"> Next </button>



<div id="dynamic" style="display:none"> 
table 2   
        <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!!! it works!!!!!!!!!! Thank you so much!!!! been fiddling around with this for nearly a week (I am very clearly very new to this)

Comment: Could I ask one more Q? the above code now works but when I hit the "next button" my next table appears then it nearly immediately disappears and the form gets submitted without me having touched anything other than the next button. Would you have any idea of what is going on and how can I prevent the form from "auto submitting"? Thank you!

Comment: you can use this to prevent form submitting $("form").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
    });

Comment: thank you! and where should I put this? before the end of the div 2?

Comment: after showDiv function but try to understand instead of just copy paste

Comment: just to make sure I am getting this right, is this last Function you suggested in jQuery? Trying to research how to get this to work. Thanks again!

Comment: yes its jquery but you can do it with javascript submit event

Answer (score 0):

Confusingly, `display: none` can't be cancelled out by setting `visibility` to `visible`. The `display` property determines how the layout engine positions the div, and the `visibility` property determines whether it is rendered. So if you start off the div with

```
<div id="dynamic" style="visibility:hidden">
```

It should work fine. I generally don't recommend hiding stuff using `display: none` because it forces the browser to re-layout the window which can move elements around. Using `visibility` means that everything stays still.

Comment: Thank you Duncan, I didn't know! seems obvious now that you guys explained... Thank you!!

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your coding!

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.getElementById("div1").style.display == "none")
{
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "";//show it
}
else
{
    document.getElementById("div1").style.display = "none";//hide it
}
```